# C++ return vector of interface ptr

Tags: c++, templates, interface, polymorphism, c++14

I am trying to create an interface that return a vector of interface, while using it implemented on an other side.

I know it's not clear, so here are examples:

```
class IComponent
{
  public:
    virtual ~IComponent() {}

    virtual int getValue() const = 0;
};

class ICollection
{
  public:
    virtual ~ICollection() {}

    virtual IComponent* getComp() = 0;
};

class Component : public IComponent
{
  public:
    virtual int getValue() const { return 42; }
};

class Collection : public ICollection
{
  public:
    Collection()
    {
      m_comp = new Component();
    }
    virtual Component* getComp()
    {
      return m_comp;
    }

  private:
    Component* m_comp;
};
```

This compile and works, because `Component*` is implicitly converted to `IComponent*`. This allow me to use a fully implemented `Collection` and `Component`.

```
#include <vector>

class IComponent
{
  public:
    virtual ~IComponent() {}

    virtual int getValue() const = 0;
};

class ICollection
{
  public:
    virtual ~ICollection() {}

    virtual std::vector<IComponent*> &getComp() = 0;
};

class Component : public IComponent
{
  public:
    virtual int getValue() const { return 42; }
};

class Collection : public ICollection
{
  public:
    Collection()
    {
      m_comp.push_back(new Component());
      m_comp.push_back(new Component());
    }
    virtual std::vector<Component*> &getComp()
    {
      return m_comp;
    }

  private:
    std::vector<Component*> m_comp;
};
```

But this time I can't work with full implemented Collection and Component.

Of course it easy to understand why, because `Component *` is `IComponent *`, but strictly speaking, `std::vector<Component *>` is not `std::vector<IComponent *>`. This problem also apply with all template type, like iterators, smart_ptr, etc...

Instead, in `Collection::getComp()` I have to return a `std::vector<IComponent *>`. I can maybe cast `m_comp` while returning it (i'm not even sure it work, wouldn't it be a rvalue?). I can also store 2 `vector`, one of `Component *` and one of `IComponent *`, and keeping them in sync, but this is ugly code I think.

Is there some workaround, or some way I didn't knew to deal with it?

**MORE DETAILS:**

What I would really like is to be able to use `Component` in `Collection`. If I change `m_comp` to `std::vector<IComponent *>` and the `getComp()` return type it will work, but I will be forced to use pointers to `IComponent` and not to `Component` in `Collection`.

So yeah I can sync two vectors, or create a copy in `getComp()`, but I want to know if there is a better way of doing it.

**EVENT MORE DETAILS:**

Here is an example on how I would like to use it:
(I simply added `getDouble()` method in `Component` and called it in `Collection`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class IComponent
{
  public:
    virtual ~IComponent() {}

    virtual int getValue() const = 0;
};

class ICollection
{
  public:
    virtual ~ICollection() {}

    virtual std::vector<IComponent*> &getComp() = 0;
};

class Component : public IComponent
{
  public:
    virtual int getValue() const { return 42; }
    double getDouble() const { return 3.14; }
};

class Collection : public ICollection
{
  public:
    Collection()
    {
      m_comp.push_back(new Component());
      m_comp.push_back(new Component());
    }
    // Impossible because it does not override the good method
    virtual std::vector<Component*> &getComp()
    {
      std::cout << m_comp[0]->getDouble() << std::endl;
      return m_comp;
    }

  private:
    std::vector<Component*> m_comp;
};
```

If I change the return type, Collection become:

```
class Collection : public ICollection
{
  public:
    Collection()
    {
      m_comp.push_back(new Component());
      m_comp.push_back(new Component());
    }
    virtual std::vector<IComponent*> &getComp()
    {
      // This time this line is impossible without cast
      // because m_comp[0] is IComponent*
      std::cout << m_comp[0]->getDouble() << std::endl;
      return m_comp;
    }

  private:
    std::vector<IComponent*> m_comp;
};
```

One solution would be like that:

```
class Collection : public ICollection
{
  public:
    Collection()
    {
      // Useless and redundant code here
      m_comp.push_back(new Component());
      m_icomp.push_back(m_comp.back());
      m_comp.push_back(new Component());
      m_icomp.push_back(m_comp.back());
    }
    // Impossible because it does not override the good method
    virtual std::vector<IComponent*> &getComp()
    {
      std::cout << m_comp[0]->getDouble() << std::endl;
      return m_icomp;
    }

  private:
    // Duplicated storage for "nothing"
    std::vector<Component*> m_comp;
    std::vector<IComponent*> m_icomp;
};
```

In the responses I saw, there was something about implementing a `pop()` and `push()` method, but in my project I'm using a `Map` instead of a `Collection`, and there are vector of blocks. This allow to access to a block by doing `map[y][x]`.

The problem is that the storage is fixed. One solution would be to add a method `getBlock(size_t x, size_t y)` instead. But I want to see the best I could do with the first case :)

Comment: Casting is certainly not a grand route. Pardon the obvious, but why not use `std::vector<IComponent*>` as your member and return reference type.

Comment: As I just added in my edit, I would like to be able to use pointers to `Component` in `Collection`. If I do what you said, I can't, or at least I need to do some other "useless" stuff to make it work.

Comment: Why does using pointers to `IComponent` internally cause issues?

Comment: Here it doesn't, but if I had more methods in `Component`, I would not be able to use these.

Comment: Well, you can downcast pointers to `IComponent` so you can work with pointers to `Component` internally using [dynamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). This won't work with `getComp`, though. However, if the code calling `getComp` needs pointers to `Component` rather than its interface I'd argue it's a design problem.

Comment: This is probably something you left out on purpose for simplicity, but I note in passing that your constructor allocates two `Component` objects from the heap that never get freed, causing a memory leak. You can either store smart pointers or add a destructor that deletes every pointer in the vector, all of which you must make sure contain unique pointers allocated by new.

Comment: If what you need is `Component` than why you creating `IComponent`? If you know that you will sore only a `Component` and not a `Component2` your collection interface should return `Component` and not `IComponent`

Comment: This is because we have a Core program and some game and graphic lib that have to be fully abstracted, so to transmit the map to display, I abstracted it. In my map I have vector of vector of blocks. In my example `Collection` = `Map` and `Component` = `Block`. Because the game with an implementation must work with any graphic lib, we have to abstract everything.

Comment: From your worlds I assumed that your graphic lib can only use `IComponent` but you in your part of the code (different then this lib) would like to use a `Component`. And probably for performance reason you don't want to copy vecrot<Component*> to vector<IComponent*>. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah that's it!

Comment: If I remember it right you can't do it by default as vector with default allocator does managed memory by itself. But instead default allocator you could create a custom allocator that could instead of creating a object, point to memory that already holds that object. But this is not easy solution and I never tested it by myself. Second more easier solution is to do accessor function for your `Collection` that will work like `at` or `[]` and return proper element casted to `Component*` from `IComponent*`. Your graphic lib will not know about it but you can use it to access proper element.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be a better idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that this solution can work in your case but... what about pass the `Component` derived class as template parameter in `ICollection` ?

Not exactly the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern but something similar.

I mean, something like

```
template <typename CompT>
class ICollection
{
  public:
    virtual ~ICollection() {}

    virtual std::vector<CompT*> &getComp() = 0;
};
```

So `Collection` become

```
class Collection : public ICollection<Component>
{
  public:
    Collection()
    {
      m_comp.push_back(new Component());
      m_comp.push_back(new Component());
    }
    virtual std::vector<Component*> &getComp()
    {
      return m_comp;
    }

  private:
    std::vector<Component*> m_comp;
};
```

or even, if you transform `Collection` in a template class

```
template <typename CompT>
class Collection : public ICollection<CompT>
{
  public:
    Collection()
    {
      m_comp.push_back(new CompT());
      m_comp.push_back(new CompT());
    }
    virtual std::vector<CompT*> &getComp()
    {
      return m_comp;
    }

  private:
    std::vector<CompT*> m_comp;
};
```

Comment: Works great unless the OP needs to access the collection through an `ICollection<IComponent>`. Does he or she?

Comment: @Davislor - well... the real problem is that the example that the OP propose is (I suppose) a semplified version of a more complex problem so... if my solution can solve (I hope) the semplified version, we don't know (only the OP knows) if it can solve the more complex problem.

Comment: It's nice but it doesn't really help me here (or I didn't understood), I edit my post again to make my problem more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the elements of the returned `vector` point to `Component` objects, you can:

```
Collection coll;
std::vector<IComponent*>& v = coll.getComp();
Component& comp = *dynamic_cast<Component*>(v[0]);
```

If you only need the virtual methods from the `IComponent` interface, you don’t even need to cast; you can just use dynamic dispatch to call them.  But casting to a reference of the daughter type will get you any methods it adds.

I also suggest making your abstraction a bit less leaky.  You can access the elements through `operator[]`, `push()/pop()`, or whatever makes sense.  Then the internal storage could be any kind of container of any kind of pointer and the public interface would not have to change.

A much less safe alternative is to go back to the C way.  You can take `m_comp.data()` as an `IComponent**`, cast it to `Component**`, and return that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `Collection::getComp`'s return type to `std::vector<IComponent*>&` anyways, because otherwise it cannot override `ICollection::getComp`. Since a `std::vector<IComponent*>` can also hold pointers to `Component` just change your member to that and you should be fine.

If pointers to `Component` rather than its interface are required somewhere, they can be downcast using [dynamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).